# Uncaught ReferenceError: clickDone is not defined at HTMLSpanElement.onclick (home.html:1)

Tags: javascript, web, firebase-realtime-database

In my web app, a user can create a classroom and then it will be save to the firebase database. After that, the newly created classroom and along with the old class will be retrieve and store in the **Classroom:** as shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVTVq.jpg)

All the classroom on the list can be click and should show the details of it like: Classroom ID, Teacher, Students. But whenever I do that, an error would appear on the [console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGSB9.jpg)

This is the code:

```
var userRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Classes' + '/' + user.uid);
userRef.on('child_added', function(data) {

var roomNames = data.val().TheClass;
var titsNames = data.val().Teacher;
var classD = data.val().ClassID;

var ul = document.createElement('ul');


document.getElementById('myList').appendChild(ul);


var li = document.createElement('li');

ul.appendChild(li);


Object.keys(roomNames).forEach(function(key){
   li.innerHTML += '<span 
onclick="clickDone(this)">'+roomNames[key]+'</span><ul style="display:none"> 
<li>Class Id : '+classD[key]+'</li><li>Teacher : '+titsNames[key]+'</li> 
</ul>';

  });

  function clickDone(thisVar){
    var is = thisVar.nextSibling.style.display;
    if(is == 'none'){
      thisVar.nextSibling.style.display = 'initial';
    }else{
      thisVar.nextSibling.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

 });
```

What went wrong? What did I miss? Any help from you would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The function clickDone must be global to be referred during the onclick event. Move the function clickDone outside of all code, after the last line.
AND the "li" must be created inside the loop
TRY THIS

```
var userRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Classes' + '/' + user.uid);
userRef.on('child_added', function(data) {

    var roomNames = data.val().TheClass;
    var titsNames = data.val().Teacher;
    var classD = data.val().ClassID;

    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    document.getElementById('myList').appendChild(ul);

    Object.keys(roomNames).forEach(function(key){
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        ul.appendChild(li);
        li.innerHTML += '<span onclick="clickDone(this)">'+roomNames[key]+'</span><ul style="display:none">' + 
            '<li>Class Id : '+classD[key]+'</li><li>Teacher : '+titsNames[key]+'</li>' +
            '</ul>';
        });

});

function clickDone(thisVar){
    var is = thisVar.nextSibling.style.display;
    if(is == 'none'){
      thisVar.nextSibling.style.display = 'initial';
    }else{
      thisVar.nextSibling.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Mr. Piero. But the bad part is that, whenever I click a classroom more than once, it will divide itself like into pieces and then show me the details.. Example: (Click once) BSIT - (x)Teacher: Piero /n (x)Classroom ID: xxxx-xxxx. (Click 2nd time in the middle): BS - (x)Teacher...(x)Classroom ID.. IT-  (x)Teacher...(x)Classroom ID then (Click the last letter) BSI - (x)Teacher:...(x)ClassroomID... T - (x)Teacher:...(x)ClassroomID..

Comment: try with the "li" created inside the rooms loop

Comment: which part? sorry I don't get it

Comment: that part: var li = document.createElement('li');
        ul.appendChild(li); // I've edited the answer to clarify

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm gonna try it later